# No Modify Permissions After Application Installation

Tags: .net, ms-access, permissions

I have an application and within the directory the application resides is an App_Data folder. Within the App_Data folder resides a front-end Access file containing stored queries. This front-end file accesses the back-end file that is located on a network drive. For whatever reason, when I install the application on a client machine and the application is launched, the application is unable to open the front-end file.

**"The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '[ApplicationPath][front-end].accdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."**

Upon checking the folder permissions after installation, the USERS group have no modify permissions. Is there any particular reason it would install without those permissions? The front-end file only contains queries which would not require modify permissions, unless because it is linked to the back-end which contains the tables which do need modify permissions, then the front-end would as well? Not sure how the best way to go about correcting this issue is.

Is there a way to have this application install and grant modify permissions to the folder which the front-end resides in?

Comment: Did you install in C:\program files\your_app_folder ?

Comment: @steve I did, and have the same problem as OP. Is that a reason for this to happen?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but to open an Access file, a locking file (ldb) is automatically created in the same folder of the main db. If you don't have permissions to write there it is possible to get errors like the one above. Try to open the file in read/only mode and look if you get the same error